# PolymerJS: How to install paper-submenu?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, material-design

I'd like to try out the [paper-submenu element](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu#paper-submenu).

But I can't find the bower-command to install the element. The page of the paper-submenu is here:

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-menu

But the command

> bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-menu

does not install the `paper-submenu` along.

and just using

> bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-submenu

does throw an error.

**Where do I get the `paper-submenu` element?**

---

### Update

It was suggested to just install the `paper-menu` element via bower. I believe that I made it clear that I did exactly this with the commands I posted above.

Here are some screenshots of my folder structure so that you can see what gets installed when I install the `paper-menu` element through the above bower command:

[image: Console]

[image: Folder Structure]

**As you can see there is NO `paper-submenu` element installed along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [git repo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu) for `paper-menu` you'll see the file for `paper-submenu` is there too, so to use `paper-submenu` you only need to install `paper-menu` and import is as `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-submenu.html">`

Comment: You mean I should "manually" copy the file from the git repo and also copy every other dependency of the paper-submenu along?

Comment: No, I mean you should install paper-menu using bower and paper-submenu will already be there too (bear in mind it needs to be one of the latest versions)

Comment: Apparently I don't need to just install `paper-menu` because the `paper-submenu´ does not get installed automatically, see added screenshots.

Comment: Check the version that was installed (it should be on the bower.json for paper-menu), if it's not version 1.1.0 or higher then it won't have paper-submenu as that was added in version [1.1.0](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu/releases). If you had a previous version installed try installing it like this `bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-menu#^1.1.0`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should import `paper-menu` element , it's coming with paper-submenu, here is a code pen example.
I used `polygit` for my imports in code pen settings
[paper-submenu example](http://codepen.io/jeanpokou/pen/eprMEQ?editors=100)